# Cocoa messes path up?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, widget

I'm trying to create an app that has an todays widget extension. This app should simply access a folder full of pictures, load them and draw them to the screen. One picture every hour. The widget should do the same, widget wise.
While loading an image in the main app and drawing it to the screen works flawlessly doing this:

```
NSString *tildePath = @"~/Documents/Adrian/Art/desertMovie.jpg";
NSString *path = [tildePath stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
_image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

the extension completely messes up the path. It uses the same code as the main application but obscures the path completely.

From:

```
~/Documents/Adrian/Art/desertMovie.jpg
```

to:

```
/Users/Adrian/Library/Containers/ac.at.hulala.AK.ImageViewer2.ImageViewerWidget/Data/Documents/Adrian/Art/desertMovie.jpg
```

If I use a path without "~" the path stays the same but the image still doesn't get loaded.

Can someone tell my what I have to do that it accesses the same folder the main application does?

EDIT:
Archiving the app and exporting it seems to fix that problem. However I still would like to know how to make this working while developing.

EDIT2:
This is so weird! When working with the Todays Extension Widget a path like `@"~/Pictures` would lead to `/Users/Me/Libraries/Containers/ac.at.ImageViewerWidget/Data/` like what the f***, why!?
When I force it to use the path `@"/Users/Me/Documents/Pictures` and run it the Memory Usage steadily increases until it reaches the limit and my system goes to hell. I really don't get that. I guess that the widget isn't finding any files so it tries to load the whole ssd. I guess. I really don't know whats the problem here.

Can someone please lead me into the light?

Comment: I would really need some help on this. I also din't find anything on apples documentation about extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that xcode would tell you if something is wrong with your app. It will just allocate your whole memory and burn your cpu,

UNTIL,

you realize that the problem is caused by the lack of folder accessing permissions. Geezuz!
Add folder access permissions to your application if you want to access something!